# Error Setting WildFly 10 Resource Adapter (wmq.jmsra.rar)

Tags: wildfly, websphere-mq

IBM MQ 9, JVM 8, Wildfly 10

**Error log wildfly:**

```
2017-09-15 10:53:33,955 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (default task-16) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceException: MQJCA1011: No se ha podido asignar una conexión JMS., error code: MQJCA1011 Un error interno ha hecho que falle un intento de asignar una conexión. Consulte la excepción enlazada para obtener detalles de la anomalía.
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:169)   
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl$TrackingExecutor$1.run(EndpointImpl.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: No se ha podido conectar con el gestor de colas 'MQ.TEST.01' con modalidad de conexión 'Client' y nombre de host '192.16.39.210(6414)'.
Compruebe que el gestor de colas esté iniciado y, si se está ejecutando en modalidad de cliente, compruebe que haya un escucha en ejecución. Consulte la excepción enlazada para obtener más información.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:595)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:422)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQXAConnection.<init>(WMQXAConnection.java:67)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:188)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7814)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createProviderXAConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:98)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createXAConnectionInternal(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:354)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAConnectionFactory.createXAConnection(MQXAConnectionFactory.java:131)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.ConnectionBuilder.createConnection(ConnectionBuilder.java:134)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: La llamada de IBM MQ ha fallado con código de terminación '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') razón '2058' ('MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
    ... 98 more

2017-09-15 10:53:33,958 INFO  [stdout] (default task-16) MQJCA0002: Se ha producido una excepción en la capa IBM MQ. Consulte la excepción enlazada para obtener detalles.
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Debes explicar porque te surje este error, darnos algo de contexto...

Answer (score 0):

Respondidas en SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46241738/error-setting-wildfly-10-resource-adapter-wmq-jmsra-rar/46241992#46241992

El error es este:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: La llamada de IBM MQ ha fallado con código de terminación '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') razón '2058' ('MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR').
```

Esto indica que el gestor de colas que se escucha en `172.16.34.210(1414)` no se llama `MQ.MQAWSHOM.01`.  Compruebe que el IP y el puerto son correctos para el gestor de colas que desea conectarse, si son correcto Compruebe cualquier faltas de ortografía en el nombre del gestor de colas que especifica.

---

Si tu hacer no cuidado qué nombre de administrador de cola está escuchando en la IP y el puerto especificados puede prefijo el nombre del gestor de colas con un `*` carácter, esto dará instrucciones a la API de ignorar el nombre del gestor de colas.  Por ejemplo: `*MQ.MQAWSHOM.01`.

Comment: Hola Josh.. el lenguaje oficial del sitio es español, por lo tanto traduce tu respuesta o sera eliminada.

Comment: Trató de traducir a español.

Comment: Gracias @JoshMc !